# Static content not served with the Gorilla mux router- like style.css,script.js

Tags: go, gorilla

I am very beginner of Go language. I an trying to serve static containt with Gorrila Mux router. But css and js is not server in my case.

```
  project
   f-mymux.go 
   d-pages
         f-home.html
         f-about.html
   d-public
        d-css
           f-style.css
        d-js
           f-script.js
```

Note: f- file & d- directory

My GO code as below:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    serverWeb()
}

var staticPages = populateStaticPages()

func serverWeb() {
    gorillaRoute := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    gorillaRoute.HandleFunc("/", serveContent)
    gorillaRoute.HandleFunc("/{page_alias}", serveContent)
    gorillaRoute.HandleFunc("/css", serveResource)
    port := ":8080"
    log.Println("Listening at port :", port)
    http.Handle("/", gorillaRoute)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(port, nil)
    if err == nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func serveContent(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    pathX := r.URL.Path
    log.Println(pathX)
    urlParams := mux.Vars(r)
    page_alias := urlParams["page_alias"]
    if page_alias == "" {
        page_alias = "home"
    }
    staticPage := staticPages.Lookup(page_alias + ".html")
    if staticPage == nil {
        staticPage = staticPages.Lookup("404.html")
        w.WriteHeader(404)
    }
    staticPage.Execute(w, nil)
}

func populateStaticPages() *template.Template {
    result := template.New("template")
    templatePaths := new([]string)
    basePath := "pages"
    templateFolder, _ := os.Open(basePath)
    defer templateFolder.Close()
    templatePathsRow, _ := templateFolder.Readdir(-1)
    for _, pathInfo := range templatePathsRow {
        log.Println(pathInfo.Name())
        *templatePaths = append(*templatePaths, basePath+"/"+
            pathInfo.Name())
    }
    result.ParseFiles(*templatePaths...)
    return result
}

//---------------------------------------------
// Serve resource of types css, js & img files
//---------------------------------------------

func serveResource(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := "./public" + r.URL.Path
    var contentType string
    if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".css") {
        contentType = "text/css; charset=utf-8"
    } /* else if strings.HasSuffix(path , ".png"){
        contentType = "image/png; charset=utf-8"
       } else if strings.HasSuffix(path , ".jpg"){
        contentType = "image/jpg; charset=utf-8"
       } else if strings.HasSuffix(path , ".js"){
       contentType = "application/javascript; charset=utf-8"
       } else {
         contentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
       }*/

    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err == nil {
        defer f.Close()
        w.Header().Add("Content-Type", contentType)
        br := bufio.NewReader(f)
        br.WriteTo(w)
    } else {
        w.WriteHeader(404)
    }
}
```

when I am invoking code
      http://localhost:8080/home
then page come witout css and js.When invoking page http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.min.css then 404 staus code come

Please help me what am doing wrong here.
We can do easily on Java and java server. But on Go lang I spend a whole day but
unable to resolve the issue.
Your help is appropriated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `http.FileServer` as documented in gorilla's readme [here](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#static-files).

Comment: [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/KwwmnVhh7N).

Comment: Thanks for reply :-)
I want to know that whether or not public folder to be inside application

Answer (score 2):

As mkopriva stated, `http.FileServer` is the way to go. Your public folder can be wherever or whatever you want it to be as long as its referenced properly as the `http.FileServer` argument.

Adding this would work:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public"))
gorillaRoute.PathPrefix("/js/").Handler(fs)
gorillaRoute.PathPrefix("/css/").Handler(fs)
```

That way a `GET` request to `http://[host]:[port]/css/style.css` will return `style.css` from the relative `./public/css/` directory.